# Java Reactor -> service overloaded with http calls

Tags: java, mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, flux

I have a service communicating with another service via REST. The call is wrapped in a Mono:

```
return Mono.from(buildPublisher(requestDto))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty())
            .map(this::mapResponse);
```

I need to make tens of thousands of calls to that service so am calling the above method  from here:

```
return Flux.fromStream(hugeListOfObjects.stream())
                .flatMap(serviceWhichReturnsMono::makeACallAndReturnMono);
```

it works fine for 200 or 2000 elements, but for a bigger number like over 20000 I get 503 (no error/exception neither on calling service nor client service).

I have a workaround (which is the only way that it actually works) and which looks like this:

```
List<List<SomeObject>> partitions = Lists.partition(hugeListOfObjects, SECURITIES_PARTITION_SIZE);

            return Flux.fromStream(partitions.stream())
                .flatMap(s ->
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(PARTITION_DELAY);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return Flux.fromStream(s.stream()).flatMap(serviceWhichReturnsMono:: makeACallAndReturnMono);
                });
```

however this is ugly and I should be using the reactor api properly. So I did try with different ways like :

```
return Flux.fromStream(securities.stream())
                .buffer(200)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
                .flatMap(s -> Flux.fromStream(s.stream()).flatMap(serviceWhichReturnsMono:: makeACallAndReturnMono, 3));
```

so I used buffer, window, flatMap((), threadNumber) etc to somehow control the traffic and allow the client service to finish the execution of chunks before being fed with more requests. All of these return 503 as in the first example above. Any idea what might be wrong? Is there a way to only send out a number of requests and wait until they complete before sending the next ones?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first `flatmap` is subscribed to 256(default `concurrency`) inner streams simultaneously. This means that 256 `List`s of 200 items are proceeding simultaneously.

```java
Flux.fromStream(securities.stream())
                .buffer(200)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
                .flatMap(s -> Flux.fromStream(s.stream()).flatMap(serviceWhichReturnsMono:: makeACallAndReturnMono, 3));
```

Instead, you probably want to use something similar to:

```java
Flux.fromIterable(hugeListOfObjects)
        .window(200)
        .flatMap(batch -> batch.flatMap(this::makeACallAndReturnMono), 1)
```

In this way, a request is made for 1 batch of 200 items. Only after that batch has been processed is when `flatMap` makes the next request and receives the next batch.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response, but this also returns 503 for over 20k requests, when I changed window from 200 to 20, then even smaller number of requests started to tail as well -> for 2200 requests. When looking into the logs it looks like every second or so it sends out chunks of 200 requests at once, so I can see 200 logs of request sent added at once every second or so...

Comment: I am also not sure if this is important but a result of processing all requests is a Flux<SomeObject>, which then in the endpoint is reduced to a Mono and returned. So to sum up:
1st service endpoint based on input produces a lot of rest calls (each returns a mono) to another service -> which is flatMaped to Flux of returns, then this flux is reduced to a mono and returned in 1st service (Mono<ResponseEntity<1stServiceResponse>>)

Comment: Also the 2nd service does not return a mono itself, but a normal ResponseEntity<body> which is wrapped in a mono in 1st service.

Comment: @lpiotrow If it didn't work for batch size 20 then the server is probably too slow or has a limit on the number of requests per second/minute.

Answer (score -1):

I got it fixed with change in application.yml:

```
spring:
  mvc:
    async:
      request-timeout: -1
```